# JAXB unmarshalling ends up in SAXParseException at the end of an InputStream

Tags: xml, svn, xsd, jaxb, jsch

I'm working on a short application which should read out some meta data from project in an SVN repository.

SVN itself offers some command line tools. One of this tools is "SVN list". The list command can delivers an xml if option --xml is given. So if you want to summarize or accumulate some data you can make it with linux (OS in our case) commands. But the minute you want to have different data and the repository gets bigger it gets too complex and slow (from my point of view).

My solution uses JSch to establish a connection and retrieve an xml for a given repository path. Next step would be to unmarshall  the xml with JAXB into classes and iterate afterwards through the objects (in theory).

So I have
- the xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <lists>
    <list
       path="<URL>/svn/Repository/<anyProject>/trunk">
    </list>
    </lists>
```

- the xsd

  ```
  <xsd:complexType name="listsType">
      <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="list" type="listType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="listType">
      <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="entry" type="entryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="path" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="entryType">
      <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="size" type="xsd:integer"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xsd:element name="commit" type="commitType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="kind" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="commitType">
      <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>          
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="revision" type="xsd:long"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
  ```
- the mapped classes (referring to the xsd)

But whenever I shoot for the unmarshalling I receive this Exception:

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 9; Content is not allowed in prolog]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:125)
    at my.organisation.repo.util.RepoJaxbUtil.unmarshal(RepoJaxbUtil.java:32)
    at my.organisation.repo.util.RepoJaxbUtil.unmarshal(RepoJaxbUtil.java:25)
    at my.organisation.repo.tool.RepoFull.start(RepoFull.java:114)
    at my.organisation.repo.managing.RepoToolManager.start(RepoToolManager.java:107)
    at my.organisation.repo.managing.RepoToolManager.main(RepoToolManager.java:43)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 9; Content ist nicht zulässig in angehängtem Abschnitt.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1431)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
... 8 more
```

I already researched a lot here and elsewhere - but never could find something about the END OF STREAM (I'm not naive - I know there is now END OF STREAM in Streams or Arrays etc)

Some more Details:
From JSch I receive an InputStream which I store in a ByteBuffer:

```
public ByteBuffer sendCommandForInputStream(String command) {
        try {
            Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();

            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(commandOutput);

            ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
            channel.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (IOException ioX) {
            logWarning(ioX.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        catch (JSchException jschX) {
            logWarning(jschX.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have to use the Buffer because if I just close the connection after I opened it, I'm not 100% the result is complete.

The unmarshal method takes an InputStream as well - so I have to "convert" it back. Maybe here lays the bug anywhere:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class RepoJaxbUtil {
    public static <T> T unmarshal(ByteBuffer xml, Class<T> clss) throws JAXBException, SAXException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("subversionRepo.xsd"));
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clss.getPackage().getName());
        InputStream xmlS = newInputStream(xml);
        return unmarshal(jaxbContext, schema, xmlS, clss);
    }

    public static <T> T unmarshal(JAXBContext jaxbContext, Schema schema, InputStream xml, Class<T> clss) throws JAXBException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xml);
        return clss.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSource));
    }

    public static InputStream newInputStream(final ByteBuffer buf) {
        return new InputStream() {
            public synchronized int read() throws IOException {
                if (!buf.hasRemaining()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return buf.get();
            }

            public synchronized int read(byte[] bytes, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                // Read only what's left
                len = Math.min(len, buf.remaining());
                buf.get(bytes, off, len);
                return len;
            }
        };
    }
  }
/*(The transfer to a InputSource does not work => just the line from 6 to 7 and the other way around)*/
```

Does anybody know how to make work around this?

Comment: Your XML is apparently invalid. It is hard to say where exactly the problem is as you have a number of steps where it can go wrong. You'll just need to carefully debug it.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution by myself after @lexicore (thank you) stated the given xml as invalid.

The xml itself was correct, but the handling within the JSch Handler class was incorrect. The issue laid in the method 'newInputStream(final ByteBuffer buf)' in the class RepoJaxbUtil. After the last character of the inputstream I set '-1' which led to the invalid xml content.

I changed the return type and name in my JSch SSH Handler:

```
     public StringBuffer sendCommandForBuffer(String command) {

        StringBuffer outputBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            int readByte = commandOutput.read();

            while (readByte != 0xffffffff) {
                outputBuffer.append((char) readByte);                
                readByte = commandOutput.read();
            }

            return outputBuffer;
        }
        catch (IOException ioX) {
            logWarning(ioX.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        catch (JSchException jschX) {
            logWarning(jschX.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

on the other hand I reviewed the class RepoJaxbUtil and 'eliminated' the threadsafety for simplicity sake (I'm quite sure this will not cause problems):

```
public class RepoJaxbUtil {

     public static Object unmarshal(StringBuffer xml, Class clss) throws JAXBException, SAXException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("subversionRepo.xsd"));
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clss.getPackage().getName());
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml.toString()));
        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
    }
}
```

Another short important advise to have could be the calling and casting in business logic class from the JAXBElement into the target object type (may it's not nice - but it worked out for my that way):

```
xmlReturn = instance.sendCommandForBuffer(cmd);
                ListsType repoLists;

                try {
                    JAXBElement lt = (JAXBElement) RepoJaxbUtil.unmarshal(xmlReturn, ListsType.class);
                    LOG.info(lt.toString());
                    repoLists = (ListsType) lt.getValue();

                    // any other business logic here

                    LOG.info("entryCount: " + repoLists.getList().getEntryType().size());
                }
                catch (JAXBException e) {
                    LOG.warn("JAXBException occured on project [" + project + "]");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (SAXException e) {
                    LOG.warn("SAXException occured on project [" + project + "]");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    LOG.warn("UnsupportedEncodingException occured on project [" + project + "]");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```